# Training ANN Keras (based Tensorflow) model on multiple h5 files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have 600 files (~ 400 MB each, total ~ 235 GB) of training data in the format "h5". All the files contain arrays with numbers, where the number of columns is the same, but the number of rows could be different.

I have experience in loading one file and training on it (code is shown below), but how to load data from that many files, shuffle them, and train the model?

```py
def load_dataset():
    """
    simply loading dataset 
    """    
    print("Start time of loading data: " + str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n\n")

    train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/data.h5', "r")

    data = np.array(train_dataset["data"][:]) 
    # Later in the code, "data" will be split into 
    # X_train and Y_train, e.g. in the comments below

    # Split data into X_train and Y_train
    # X_train_orig = data[:, :5].reshape(data.shape[0],5) 
    # Y_train_orig = data[:, -4].reshape(data.shape[0],1)

    print("End time of loading data: " + str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
    print("Load data: complete\n")

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the data points in each file are Independent and identically distributed  (IID) and if each file has good representation of all the classes (i.e not heavily biased toward one class), then load one file shuffle its contents and train on it then proceed to the next file and soon on. When you are done with the last file repeat as long as the validation score is improving.

For example Word2vec is trained on huge data data but full data is never loaded in memory. Just couple of epochs on full data converges the training, so should be in your case too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I am training a regression problem on physics data, each file represents some physical behaviour under certain conditions (for example, each file would correspond to a specific temperature and humidity conditions). I am predicting the rate of change of a specific physical attribute as a continuous function. Would it work in this case?

Comment: No, if each file represents some different behaviour then the weight will jump around. But what you can do is sample say 10% from each file and create a new file. Create 100 such files with 10% each from each file. This way each new file will represent all the characteristics. Then proceed the way I have answered above.

Comment: This is a great idea and I will definitely give it a try.